# Usar interfaces para abstrair tipo de conexao

Tags: php, design-pattern, interface

Na faculdade a gente aprende a usar o modelo `FACTORY` para conexões, mas gostaria de saber se é possível aplicar interfaces também, como no exemplo a seguir:

### Estudo de caso

Tenho uma aplicação em php que segue mais próximo possível o padrao `MVC`, mas que deveria ter a conexão independente, ou seja, caso seja necessário alterar o banco, não houvesse necessidade de reescrever a aplicação toda.

Então, foi criada no model, uma classe chamada `MySQ_LConnect`, que provê conexão com o banco `Mysql`, bem como a execução das `querys` que lhe são passadas:

```
class MYSQL_connect {

    private $hostname = 'myHost';
    private $username = 'DBUser';
    private $senha = '';
    private $banco = 'database';
    private $conn;

    public function conectar(){
        $this->conn = mysql_pconnect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->senha);
        $db = mysql_select_db($this->banco,$this->conn);
        return $this->conn;
    }

    public function executarQuery($query,$conn){
        $result = mysql_query($query,$conn);
        return $result;
    }

    public function desconectar($conn){
        mysql_close($conn);
    }
```

Pensando numa futura migração para o `sql server`, foram criadas uma classe de conexao para este banco e uma interface, só para parametrizar as duas classes de conexão agora existentes:

**Interface**

```
interface iConnect{

    public function conectar();
    public function executarQuery($query,$conexao);
    public function desconectar($conexao);
}
```

**Classe de conexao com o sqlserver**

```
class MSSQL_connect implements iConnect{

    private $hostname = 'myHost';
    private $connInfo = array("Database"=>"database", "UID"=>"DBUser", "PWD"=>"");
    private $conn;

    public function conectar(){
        $this->conn = sqlsrv_connect($this->hostname, $this->connInfo) or die(sqlsrv_errors());
        return $this->conn;
    }

    public function executarQuery($sql,$conn){
        $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql,array(),array("Scrollable"=>"buffered"));
        return $result;
    }



    public function desconectar($conn){
        sqlsrv_close($conn);
    }
}
```

Obs.: na classe `MYSQL_connect` foi implementada a interface também.

Então, no ambiente de testes, é possível alternar entre os bancos usando uma conexão `Fabrica`, onde `BANCO` é uma constante do prefixo dos bancos(só para facilitar alternar entre os bancos):

```
require_once 'MySQL_connect.php';
require_once 'MSSQL_connect.php';
define("BANCO","MySQL");//ou pode ser MSSQL
    class Fabrica{

        public function fabricar(){
            $classeDAO  = BANCO."_connect";

            return new $classeDAO;
        }       
    }
```

### Dúvida

Como usar interfaces neste caso para abstrair o tipo de conexão, semelhante ao que a classe `Fabrica` está tentando fazer, de modo que para o restante da aplicação não faça diferença em que banco está conectando?

Caso a interface não atenda bem a este requisito, como abstrair sem usar `Factory`?

Comment: Duas considerações: 1 - você está retornando a conexão `$this->conn` e  recebe `$conn` em alguns métodos, o que me parece errado, receber a conexão como parâmetro sendo que você já tem ela dentro do objeto; 2 - cada implementação de `executarQuery()` retorna um tipo diferente de recurso, para que não faça diferença na aplicação você deve retornar sempre o mesmo tipo (um *array* por exemplo). O PHP não tem uma forma nativa de forçar um tipo de retorno, então você deve tratar manualmente.

Comment: @Sanção esse lance do executarQuery() foi proposital, eu tenho outros métodos que fazem essa conversão que você disse, mas removi para que o código não ficasse gigante, mas dentro de cada classe de conexão eu tenho sim um metodo que converte o resultado num array. Quanto a variavel `$conn` foi uma dica do professor, confesso que nem pensei por esse lado kkkk

Comment: Sendo assim a única forma de melhorar suas classes seria modificar `Fabrica::fabricar()` para receber um parâmetro com o tipo do banco, com valor padrão, recomendo utilizar constantes (`const TIPO_MYSQL`)

Comment: Editei a pergunta, `BANCO` é uma constante já.

Comment: O que tem essa classe haver com `factory` ?

Comment: Não considero uso de Interfaces algo que faça generalização. O pensamento está errado. Está mais para abstração. Generalizar, é fazer algo que serve para qualquer caso. Abstração é quando você criar maneiras simples para atender de forma que dê o mínimo de condições para uma funcionalidade.

Comment: Além disso, interfaces foram feitas para  burocratizar o seu código, impedindo que outros desenvolvedores destruam a sua funcionalidade básica.

Comment: @IvanFerrer obrigado pela correção, eu quis dizer abstração, vou corrigir a pergunta.

Comment: @Edilson nessa atividade, a sugestão foi utilizar algo parecido com o padrao factory, no caso, foi a classe `Fabrica`. Não está seguindo 100% este padrao, foi só uma inspiração.

Comment: Olha, vou lhe passar um exemplo bem simples de uma fábrica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma maneira de fazer isso seria assim:

```
interface InterfaceFabrica {

   public function __construct(DatabaseConnect $databaseConnect);

}
```

Teria uma classe para o tipo como injeção de dependência:

```
class DatabaseConnect {

    const TYPE = 'MySQL';

    public function __construct($type = self::TYPE) {
        $classeDAO = $type. "_connect";
        return new $classeDAO;
   }

}
```

E a classe fábrica implemantada com sua interface de fabricação:

```
class Fabrica implements InterfaceFabrica {

   public function __construct(DatabaseConnect $databaseConnect) {
       return $this;
   }
}
```

Obrigando a passar o tipo através de uma constante, dando início a fabricação através do construtor:

```
define('DATABASE_TYPE', 'MySQL');

$databaseConnect = new DatabaseConnect(DATABASE_TYPE);

$fabrica = new Fabrica($databaseConnect);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro apenas uma melhoria, na classe `Fabrica`, usar constantes de classe:

```php
class Fabrica {

    const TIPO_MYSQL = 'MySQL';
    const TIPO_MSSQL = 'MSSQL';

    public function fabricar($banco = self::TIPO_MYSQL) {
        $classeDAO  = $banco . "_connect";
        return new $classeDAO;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para criar uma fábrica, não é propriemanete necessária uma interface, interfaces mantêm apenas a consistência. Uma das principais prioridades desse padrão, se posso assim dizer, é criar objectos sem ter de especificar a classe exata. São úteis quando se quer utilizar objectos completamente diferentes da mesma maneira. Ou seja, diferentes lógicas, mas o mesmo comportamento quando aplicadas.

```
<?php

namespace Build;

class Forma
{
    public static function getForma($forma, $area)
    {
        switch($forma):
            case 'circulo';
                return new Circulo($area);
            case 'quadrado':
                return new Quadrado($area);
            default:
                return new stdClass();          
        endswitch;  
    }
    public function getArea()
    {
        // return get_class($this)
        return $this->getArea();
    }
}

class Circulo extends Forma 
{
    private $area;
    public function __construct($area)
    {
        $this->area = $area;
    }
    public function getArea(){
        return M_PI * ($this->area)**2;
    }
}

class Quadrado extends Forma 
{
    private $area;
    public function __construct($area)
    {
        $this->area = $area;
    }
    public function getArea()
    {
        return ($this->area)**2;
    }
}

?>
```

Neste exemplo, as classes `circulo` e `quadrado` são derivadas da classe `forma`, e possuem os mesmos métodos, porem são diferentes na lógica, mas continuam a produzir o mesmo resultado, que é retornar a área correspondente. É com base nesse princípio que deves começar a trabalhar em fábricas.

```
<?php

include_once 'class.forma.php';

$forma = \Build\Forma::getForma('circulo', 3);
print $forma->getArea();
print "<br/>";
$forma = \Build\Forma::getForma('quadrado', 4);
print $forma->getArea();
print "<br/>";

?>
```

Veja o [exemplo](http://ideone.com/tp2tBm) em funcionamento.

Outro rico exemplo, é [este](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), com o uso de interfaces, onde o a fábrica de Sedan, pode produzir diferentes modelos da mesma marca, utilizando os mesmos processos. Deve ser este o teu ponto de partida.

Comment: A minha classe `Fabrica` não faz isso já?

Comment: Vejo apenas interfaces, por isso adicionei este exemplo.